# Microdata - nesting and multiple itemref

Tags: schema.org, microdata

We are using microdata on our website, and I'm wondering if multiple items can refer to another...I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

On a blog page you could have both blog posts and authors associated with an organisation, like this:

```
<article itemref="organisation" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" 
    itemscope>
    <p class="date"><meta content="2014-01-16" itemprop="datePublished" />16-01-2014</p>
    <p>by 
        <span itemref="organisation" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" 
            itemscope itemprop="author">
            <meta content="Joe Bloggs" itemprop="name" />Joe</span>
    </p>
    <h2 itemprop="name" >Awesome content here</h2>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/awesome-content-here/">Full story</a>
</article>

<div itemprop="worksFor publisher" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" 
    itemscope="" id="organisation"> 
    <meta content="MyOrg" itemprop="name">
    <a href="mailto:hello@example.com" itemprop="email">hello@myorg.com</a>
</div>
```

The organisation would be the **worksFor** for the author, and the **publisher** for the post. What I've put is invalid, worksFor and publisher are both applied to both the post and the author.

Is there a way of achieving what I'm attempting here?

Thanks!

Toby

Comment: `p` and `span` [can’t have a `content` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18898363/1591669) in Microdata (it’s only defined for the `meta` element). Either use `meta`/`link` and place the human-readable text next to it, or use the `data` attribute and its `value` attribute where appropriate.

Comment: Your `h2` contains `</a>` but has no opening `a` tag.

Answer (score -1):

As noted above:

> p and span can’t have a content attribute in Microdata (it’s only defined for the meta element). Either use meta/link and place the human-readable text next to it, or use the data attribute and its value attribute where appropriate.

Here is a sample association using the `itemref` attribute:

```
<div id="daughter" itemprop="children" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="name">Mary</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="daughter">
    <span itemprop="name">John</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="daughter">
    <span itemprop="name">Julie</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you added this, that comment was made almost two months ago and I updated my question accordingly? And it's not an answer to my question (can I associate two different items with another)?

Comment: Good point. This helps clarify the question and increase the chance of getting a good answer. The answer to a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080142/1113772) may be close.